# How to calculate the number of ways to divide a deck of cards into 4 piles so the suits are evenly distributed among the piles?

Tags: combinatorics

I know that the suits will not distribute evenly, so to make the calculation simpler let's remove the aces from the deck.  I have been really struggling with trying to find a general formula.

I tried (12, 3)^4 but it fails for the simple case of splitting a deck of 4 cards of 2 spades and 2 clubs where the answer should be 2 distinct splits.

Thanks in advance,

Pete

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't remove the aces and just say that the answer is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

12 cards in each suit (if aces are excluded), 3 cards from each suit to a pile. For each pile, count the remaining choices of cards from a suit, and repeat 4 times to account for all 4 suits. Multiply the choices for each pile together to get total choices

$$Choices_{Pile1} \times Choices_{Pile2} \times Choices_{Pile3} \times Choices_{Pile4}$$
$$=\binom{12}{3}^4 \times \binom{9}{3}^4 \times \binom{6}{3}^4 \times \binom{3}{3}^4 $$
$$=(\frac{12\cdot11\cdot10}{6})^4(\frac{9\cdot8\cdot7}{6})^4(\frac{6\cdot5\cdot4}{6})^4(1)^4$$
$$=\frac{(12\cdot11\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot5\cdot4)^4}{6^8}$$
$$=\frac{(11\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot5\cdot4)^4}{3^4}$$

This value must be divided by $4!=3\cdot2^3$ to account for the fact that the four piles would be indistinguishable from each other (in other words, the order of the piles shouldn't matter), giving the total ways to divide the deck:

$$\frac{(11\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot5\cdot4)^4}{3^5\cdot2^3}$$
$$=11^4\cdot7^4\cdot5^8\cdot3^3\cdot2^9$$
$$=189,826,421,400,000,000$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For one suit of twelve cards there are $\frac {12!}{3!^4}$ ways to distribute it.  One way to see it is to think of lining all the cards up and splitting them into groups of three.  You can order the suit in $12!$ ways.  Each group can be reordered in $3!$ ways and give the same split into four groups.  Then each suit can be split this many ways, so raise it to the fourth power, giving 
$$\frac {12!^4}{3!^{16}}\approx 1.866\cdot 10^{22}$$